# Unknown column while executing where conditions Sequelize subquery field

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I was trying to create a query that finds products with price less than or equals to avgPrice.

Below is the sample query.

```
await Product.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'id', 'name', 'price',
      [sequelize.literal(`SELECT AVG(price) from Products`), 'avgPrice']
    ],
    where: {
      price: {
        [Sequelize.Op.lte]: sequelize.col('avgPrice')
      }
    }
```

But it gives the following error.

```
Unknown column 'Products.avgPrice' in 'where clause'
```

Also I tried to copy the query generated by sequelize and execute it manually in mysql but it gives the same error.

Isn't this how we run the query?

Edit: I changed the query requirements from avgPrice < 100 to price < avgPrice. However, the problem in the question is the same.

Comment: to filter aggregate you need to use `having` instead of `where`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thanks for helping me out. So we should using having clause. Damn it! mysql should give error message like somehting else. You can post your answer.

Comment: Create your query in sql first and verify its working. Then write it in `sequelize` and check if `sequelize` is generating the same query *(semantically)* or not. It will help you in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you want to filter based on aggregated column you need to change `WHERE` clause to `HAVING`.